# Setting up JdbcTemplate in IDEA Community. Liquibase failure

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I have working program with JDBC API and want to implement JDBC Template (free version IDEA Community).

In my SpringConfig I add 2 Beans (no other changes) and right after that I receive Errror, when trying to launch the program. The error:

*Liquibase failed to start because no changelog could be found at 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'.
Action:
Make sure a Liquibase changelog is present at the configured path.*

[tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Som.png)

**What's wrong with it?**

I do not do any another changes. Nothing add to application.properties (as far as I understand it is not necessary).
In my pom.xml I have: liquibase-core, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, mysql-connector-java

the SpringConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan ("com.ko")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer  {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean //filter for _method
    public FilterRegistrationBean HiddenHttpMethodFilter (){
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new HiddenHttpMethodFilter());
        filterRegBean.setUrlPatterns(Arrays.asList("/*"));
        return filterRegBean;
    }
/*
    @Bean //first variant
    public DataSource datasSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javastudy");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }*/

    @Bean //second variant
    public DataSource datasource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                .url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javastudy")
                .username("root")
                .password("root")
                .build();
    }
    @Bean 
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){
        return new JdbcTemplate(datasource());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Liquibase dependency in your pom.xml file, you need to make a **db.changelog-master.yaml** file in order to store all the information related to making new Liquibase scripts and updating or deleting the existing Liquibase scripts. You can create this file in the **resources folder** of your project. Also if you need you have the option to choose between **yaml** and **xml** for creating this file.

Comment: I don't want to use yaml or xml for the program if it's possible. I've tried to delete "liquibase-core" dependency. But the error still stays the same. Do you know how can I launch it without any relations to liquibase ?

Comment: After removing the liquibase-core dependency, have you tried refreshing the maven dependencies i.e. mvn -> update dependencies.

Comment: O my God! It was so easy! Thank you my friend from the deepest bottom of my heart!